# Connect Nintendo 64 to a modern flat-screen TV?

Tags: nintendo-64

I bought a Nintendo 64 system and I have a 55' Vizio Smart TV.

I tried to connect the Red and White cord to my TV. There are two reds you can try on the back with the white green and blue option and one red and white for Audio on the side of the tv. I did not have any luck.

I went to Target and bought a RF Video Converter Box. You screw the black code to the antenna part on the back of the tv. On the RF box you put in the Red White and Yellow cord. I tried Comp with the three dots as an option on my tv and I tried Antenna. I searched for channels but I can not get 3 or 4.

I tried to add the 3&4 channel still no luck can someone help me please.

Comment: You may need to add some pictures, because this is hard to follow without knowing exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: Definitely get some pictures. It sounds like you're connecting composite cables to component cables. (One is Red/White/Yellow, and one is Red/White/Green/Blue/Red)

Answer (score 3):

Coincidentally, I also have a 55" Vizio TV and a Nintendo 64, my favorite console of them all, in my room. For whatever reason, I was able to get my GameCube to work with the TV, but I never could get the N64 to. I just tried it again, and went through every setting I could find on the TV, but still nothing. There's no picture, but I can hear music for not even a second before it goes silent. My Nintendo 64 definitely works, as I was playing Super Smash Bros. on it just a couple of hours ago with a different TV.

All I can tell you is make sure the N64, games, and cords work by testing with another TV and then ensure that the composite cables are connected to the Vizio TV like this:

[image]

and the input is set to "Composite". If it still doesn't work, then it's your TV. You can either return it and get another brand, get another TV for your game consoles (like I have), or mod (or pay someone to mod) your N64 to output in HDMI (however, this still isn't guaranteed to fix the problem).

Comment: The TV doesn't have to support receiving video signal like this.  Looks like it is a feature of this TV, but it doesn't hurt to try it.

Comment: Seriously, this post just made my night. My best friend and of thirty years and I got together today. He'd found a home movie we'd made in 1999 of another buddy who died recently. We went to Goodwill and they tracked an old VCR in the back of the store room. We got it home and couldn't figure out how to get the video channel up on this new Vizio TV.... until right now. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be, if the TV doesnt want to take it, to buy a converter between the AV and HDMI format.

https://www.walmart.com/ip/Fosmon-174-RGB-YPbPr-Component-AV-to-HDMI-Converter-with-R-L-Metal-Casing-Comes-with-AC-Adapter/41475189

If your TV doesnt take it by itself, you propably need something to convert the N64 signal to something readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a model for the TV I could look for the manual for it.

My suggestions would be to make sure that the 64 works on another TV first. You should be able to connect your composite cables directly to the TV (Red, White, Yellow), and note that yellow is the cable that carries video.

"Comp" on your TV might refer to computer, like VGA, DVI, or something. Look for composite specifically or A/V

Answer (score 0):

You can actually connect any composite (Red, White, and Yellow) cabled device to component (Green, Blue, and Orange video with Red and White audio) ports simply by plugging the yellow video cable into the green component jack, as RedEagle shows in their picture.  Just switch to the input, which will be called Component by default or possibly switch to Composite if the TV recognizes the difference, and you should be good to go.  Just make sure that nothing is plugged into the blue and orange jacks, as the TV will try to get a signal from those as well and the picture will be messed up as a result.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with some specific Vizio models. My model is a D58u-D3 and I'm guessing similar models will have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the TV.  I have a Vizio D58u-D3 and my N64, SNES don't work, but they work just fine on my Vizio E320-B2.  I do notice that on screen where it shows my resolution, the D58 TV, goes blank... where on my E320 TV it shows 480i.  My thought is the newer of the Tv's is struggling to manage the frame rate, possibly too low?

Answer (score -2):

[image: N64 plugs]

Yellow goes in green

Put video source to "Comp/AV"

Blow in your game. Like realllly blow hard

Magically transport to childhood

Comment: The cables in the picture are connected incorrectly. The right-channel audio cable is plugged into the Pr component input.